# Elementary Question (Graphic Design)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Why do designers separate out letters in Adobe Illustrator? I can't seem to find the answer. I know it's an elementary design question but what is the design function behind separating them out? This question is hard to put to Google. Thank you in advance to the wonderful people out there who help noobs like me.

Comment: What do you mean by "separating them out"? Do you mean creating outlines of type?

Comment: Please show a visual example.

Comment: Please make your title more descriptive once you are able to clarify your question, so that others can find it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If by *separate out* you mean make text so that it can’t be edited with a text tool, the correct term is *create outlines*.

Specific to vector drawing applications such as Adobe Illustrator, type can be defined as being part of a font, which can be edited as a word processor would, or reduced to the outline curves which describe the letter shapes. This form is no longer able to be edited for its content, as it is now only a picture of letters.

If an Illustrator file is given to someone who does not have the font you used, such as a printer, the file will not open correctly because the font is missing. That’s why, usually as the last step, the fonts in the document are changed into outlines. The outlines do not need the font information in order to print correctly.

This is the primary reason. Another important reason is that if the designer wants to change the way letters look, such as in a logo design, first they have to convert the type into outlines in order to be able to manipulate the shapes.

Comment: This could be the answer to the question. But its eqally possible that OP is opening the file in a second application where kerning is not well supported so the application splits the text into multiple segments. Yeah, then the designer does not split the text, but rather the import/export splits the text.

Comment: @joojaa I agree that because of the vagueness of the question there are several answers possible. I like your comment because it involves importing/placing a document in a wider variety of applications, not necessarily limited to other graphics software.

Comment: Also, even when providing the fonts, occasionally there can be font-version collisions when submitting to a printer and converting to outlines avoids this rare possibility.